# scjp question ? what is Au exception here 

Tags: java

```
11. public static void test(String str) { 
12. if(str == null | str.lellgth() == 0) { 
13. System.out.println("String is empty"); 
14. } else { 
15. System.out.println("String is not empty"); 
16. } 
17. }
```

And the invocation:

```
31. test(llull);
```

> What is the result?
>   A. Au exception is thrown at runtime.
>   B. "String is empty" is printed to output.
>   C. Compilation fails because of au error in line 12.
>   D. "String is not empty" is printed to output.

Answer: A

What is Au exception here ? ...

Thanks

Comment: Who's replacing the 'n's with 'll's?

Comment: Just want to point out, apparently, this is the way the test is: http://www.techfundu.com/2010011988/java-technology/core-java/scjp-exam-prepration-questions-part-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A. Au exception is thrown at runtime.**

**if your code is**

```
11. public static void test(String str) { 
12. if(str == null | str.length() == 0) { 
13. System.out.println("String is empty"); 
14. } else { 
15. System.out.println("String is not empty"); 
16. } 
17. }
```

and

```
31. test(null);
```

`NullPointerException` will be thrown at runtime as `str` will be `null` and `length()` will be invoked on `null`

Comment: That's not true, because if the `str == null` part returns true, the `str.length()` part will not execute.

Comment: @Erick Robertson You were totally right if it was `||` in if condition , but here it is `|` , ijn your answer you have mentioned it and in my answer downvote , why :) ??

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected.  However, given the state of the question,  I have zero confidence that this isn't a simple typo.

Comment: @Erick: you've missed that it's a bitwise OR, not a logical one. This looks like a fairly standard "gotcha" type question (notwithstanding all the `n` -> `ll` typos - maybe it was scanned in from an exam paper and badly OCRed?).

Comment: I actually just assumed it was a typo and that it was supposed to be a `||`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typo in whatever test or homework assignment you're doing.  It should be "An exception".

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you want "||" and not "|" on line 12.  And 'lellgth' is spelled 'length'.  You might also want to reverse it

```
  if ( !(str == null) && !(str.trim().length == 0) {
     // string is empty
  } else {
     // string is not empty
  }
```

because the code as you have it will error out if str is null.

Answer (score 0):

The following line will not short circuit:

```
if(str == null | str.length() == 0) {
```

If you use a logical or, it will short circuit (and not test str for null)

```
if(str == null || str.length() == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have several misprints.

```
12. if(str == null | str.lellgth() == 0) {
```

should be

```
12. if(str == null | str.legth() == 0) { 

31. test(llull);
```

should be

```
31. test(null);
```

And finally,

```
A. Au exception is thrown at runtime.
```

should be

```
A. An exception is thrown at runtime.
```

---

The exception thrown at runtime will be a `NullPointerException` because of this line:

```
if(str == null | str.lellgth() == 0)
```

The line uses a bitwise or `|` instead of a logical or `||`.

Comment: The most interesting thing is that it compiles fine :)

Comment: @khachik: Yes, unfortunately Java doesn't warn you when you do a bitwise operation on boolean values.  I'll bet some static code analysis packages will catch it, but the compiler just assumes you know what you're doing.  ;)

Comment: yes, it is strange... It may hide programming errors. [Confusing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.2)